# sudo apt-get not working properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

While running `sudo apt-get upgrade` I got following error

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-32 linux-headers-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-32-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36+elementary11+r6~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-gfxpayload-lists:
 grub-gfxpayload-lists depends on grub-pc (>= 1.99~20101210-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-gfxpayload-lists (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub-gfxpayload-lists
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can any one tell what is wrong and how to fix it.

I also can't install any package due to this error.

`sudo apt-get -f install` output

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for pi:  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36+elementary11+r6~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2:
 grub2 depends on grub-pc (= 2.02~beta2-36+elementary11+r6~ubuntu16.04.1); however:
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-gfxpayload-lists:
 grub-gfxpayload-lists depends on grub-pc (>= 1.99~20101210-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-gfxpayload-lists (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub2
 grub-gfxpayload-lists
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/q/774663/17529

Comment: I performed `sudo dpkg --purge grub-pc grub2 grub-gfxpayload-lists` and error remain same now i can't install grub-pc I think now I will not be able to boot up my system if I shutdown  hehehe.

Comment: what does this line means `Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36+elementary11+r6~ubuntu16.04.1) ...`

Comment: It is actually same but there is little change in output as I have performed  `sudo dpkg --purge grub-pc grub2 grub-gfxpayload-lists`.

Comment: Actually looks like something's failing while installing. Can you try `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst-bad` and then run `sudo apt-get install grub-c` again? (The idea comes from [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557182&p=9747771#post9747771), but I'm not sure what the underlying problem is…)

Comment: worked I think my system has some problem with `gurb2`

Comment: can you help me to confirm that does I have broken my boot files or not!

Comment: Can you run `grub-install` now?