# Grub update not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, elementaryos

I messed up with my `GRUB` [sudo apt-get not working properly](https://superuser.com/questions/1270224/sudo-apt-get-not-working-properly)

I am trying to rebuild it so that my system can boot properly i am using external usb to login to my system

```
root@elementary:/# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 966.1 MiB, 1013055488 bytes, 1978624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xabdfae9c

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 1953523711 1952522242  931G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 1953523711 1952522240  931G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7751073792 bytes, 15138816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6f215e7b

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        0 2648063 2648064  1.3G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2        5324   10187    4864  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root: 923.1 GiB, 991193726976 bytes, 1935925248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1: 7.9 GiB, 8493465600 bytes, 16588800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

when I performed `sudo update-grub2`

```
root@elementary:/# sudo update-grub2
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
Found elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki (0.4.1) on /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

There is an error in output

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
```

and I am still getting `Grub>` terminal when i boot my system.

How can I fix this.

EDIT 1:

I Installed Boot-Repair

It asked if i have RAID I clicked NO

Then it prompted this message

```
The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Do you want to continue?
```

Edit 2 :

[BIOS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjoYw.jpg)

Edit 3:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6eJV.jpg)

[This is the error which i am getting that is what i am trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Ngu.jpg)

Comment: Open UEFI settings and you should find another EFI boot entry. Select that one as the first boot priority. If the same error, boot a live session and follow instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair (2nd option), do NOT apply any fix at this moment but create the summary instead, then [edit] your question and post the link so we can take a look at it. (Ping me using @MichaelBay in a comment when done).

Comment: @MichaelBay I installed Boot-Repair then when I ran it. It promoted me  this message `The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Do you want to continue?`

Comment: That means you installed ElementaryOS in Legacy mode (BIOS) in a UEFI based machine. Please boot the live session in the same Legacy mode otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have added my bios image above

Comment: Change it to Legacy and perhaps that's enough for it to boot. If not, boot the live session and run Boot-Repair as explained before. PS - You *must* know how you're installing operating system and how to set UEFI accordingly (you DON'T have BIOS, you have what replaces BIOS and it's called Unified Extended Firmware Interface). More info at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Change boot mode to legacy, *then* boot the live session with the USB. There's no way that message can appear if you're booting in legacy mode.

Comment: I have updated the image in edit 3 section

Comment: Needless to say, you want Legacy only, not "legacy enabled + UEFI first". Shouldn't be that hard to understand: How it boots is how it installs (and how it runs a live session), Boot-Repair has been booted in UEFI mode and complained about no having an EFI partition; that suggests Legacy install, so the live session must be booted in such way as to allow Boot Repair to work.

Comment: Ok then i have to boot my pen drive to legacy mode instead of UEFI mode ok i understood now.

Comment: @MichaelBay now every thing is done but at the end I am getting `No internet connection detected. Please connect internet. Then try again.` Error

Comment: You're booting a live session. Preferably use a LAN cable (Ethernet) that just works. If WiFi -and- your WiFi chipset is supported out of the box, simply connect to your network the usual way. But there's more:

Comment: I went to advance setting then deselected check for Internet option then i got this error `grub-pc purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com`

Comment: I noticed in your latest screenshot the mention of "i386", meaning 32-bit. So, you not only installed the OS in Legacy mode where you shouldn't but also a 32-bit OS in an 64-bit PC. Better to use that live session to backup what you need to another drive, make an USB with the 64-bit OS, change the settings again to UEFI only and install afresh.

Comment: @MichaelBay i386-pc means legacy PC BIOS (Which always run in 32bit mode for compatibility). While x86_64-efi is UEFI which runs in 64-bit mode. This doesn't mean the CPU isn't 64bit and it doesn't mean the OS isn't 64bit. For posterity there is also a i386-efi target in grub.

Comment: Looking at the output for /dev/sdb appears to be a protective MBR meaning the disk is actually GPT. Try using a tool like gdisk instead.